# Creating new Calc Document (OpenOffice) in C#

Tags: c#, openoffice.org, calc

i'm trying to open new Calc document, and i'm getting this error:

System.IO.FileLoadException: Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.

Cli references are inlcuded in project.

```
    void OpenSpreadsheetClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XComponentContext oStrap = uno.util.Bootstrap.bootstrap();
    //The next step is to use OpenOffice.org's service manager to create a desktop:
    XMultiServiceFactory oServMan = (XMultiServiceFactory) oStrap.getServiceManager();
    XComponentLoader oDesk = (XComponentLoader) oServMan.createInstance("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop" );
    string url = @"private:factory/scalc";
    PropertyValue[] propVals = new PropertyValue[0];
    XComponent oDoc = oDesk.loadComponentFromURL(url, "_blank", 0, propVals);
    }
```

How to fix it?
Tnx for help :)

Comment: Adding configuration file fixed the problem: <configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you need to this to your app.config:

```
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/> 
  </startup>
```

Check out this (somewhat related) post for more info: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jomo_fisher/archive/2009/11/17/f-scripting-net-4-0-and-mixed-mode-assemblies.aspx

Edit: If you want to find out more about what the useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy flag actually does, MSDN has a page on it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx34a2h.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Set your Target Framework in your project to 3.5 or 2.0.